# How to save file after it had been edited with jquery using php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here I created a jquery function that gets css-color and creates element with background of css-color: **[Edit my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FoxKiD/8USqU/)**

## html

```
<div ID="wrapper">
    <div ID="addColor">
        <input type="text" ID="hex">
        <div ID="color">Your color</div>
        <button ID="add">Add color</button>
    <div CLASS="clear"></div> <!-- Clear float -->
    </div>

    <div ID="wrapGallery">
        <h1>My Color Gallery</h1>
        <ul ID="gallery"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

## js/jquery

```
$(function() {
    //float left with some margin
    $('#addColor')
        .children().not('#add, .clear').css({
        'float':'left',
        'margin-right': '5px'
        });

    //Showing color on keyup
    $('#hex').keyup(function() {
       var hexCode = $(this).val();
       $('#color').css('background-color', hexCode);

        if ( hexCode !== '') {
            $('#color').text('');
        }else{
            $('#color').text('Your color');
        }

    });

    //Adding colors
    $gallery = $('#gallery');

    $('#add').click(function() {

        var storedHex = $('#hex').val();
        //check if empty
        if (storedHex == '') {
            alert('Enter something');        
        }
        else {
        //adding li
        $("<li>").css('background-color', storedHex)
                .hover(
                  function () {
                    $(this).text(storedHex);
                  }, 
                  function () {
                    $(this).text('');
                  })                    
                 .appendTo($gallery); 
        }
    });
});
```

The only thing I need to do is to save the created elements permanently in the file, so I can access whenever I want. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: save them permanently to what file?

Comment: @DavidStetler I tried passing value using form and echo that variable but do you know how to save that new variable permanently on that same file or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on JQuery Ajax function and also read about JSON objects.

With AJAX and JQuery you can easily send a JSON object to your server like so:

```
function saveElements(myJsonObj) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "path/to/savemyobject.php",
    data: {json:myJsonObj}
  });
}
```

A JSON file may look something like this:

```
{ "myData":
  {
    "some_text":"this could be the CSS code",
    "name":"some name",
    "number":"some number"
  }
}
```

You could generate a JSON string representing a JSON object and send it to a PHP file with the Ajax function (as above).

In PHP you would do this to obtain the object:

```
<?php
$json_string = $_POST["json"]; //the same variable key we sent it in
$json_obj = json_decode($json_string, true);
// get data
$myDataCode = $json_obj["myData"]["some_text"];
// do some processing
...
?>
```

You could also convert an array in PHP to a JSON object using the PHP json_encode function.

Read more:
http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: What if I pass variable and want to save on the file?

Comment: `data:{json:myJsonObj, variable:"another var"}` but I don't see why you can't just throw the variable in with the JSON object @PhoxKiD

Answer (score 3):

It is currently not possible for Javascript (in a browser) to edit/save files like you want.  However, you can use [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send the data back to a PHP file so that the PHP file can save it using [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) (though it would usually save it in a database instead).