# Sending string with json to php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

My code works great except for the "userName" for some reason sending a string through JSON will not post to table, it sends nothing.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

jquery

```
lowestScoreId = 1;
userPoints = 50;
userName = "ted";

$.getJSON("functions/updateHighScores.php", {lowestScoreId: lowestScoreId, userPoints: userPoints, userName: userName}, function(data) {

  $('#notes').text(data.userName); //for testing

});
```

php

```
lowestScoreId =  json_decode($_GET['lowestScoreId']);
$userName =  json_decode($_GET['userName']);
$userPoints =  json_decode($_GET['userPoints']);

include 'config.php';

$currentTime = time();

mysql_query("UPDATE highScores
SET `name`    = '$userName',
    `score`   = '$userPoints',
    `date`    = '$currentTime'
WHERE id='$lowestScoreId'");

echo json_encode(array("userName" => $userName));  // for testing
```

Comment: I can't see any usage of `$obj`.

Comment: I think you've got it all mixed up... there should've been 1 JSON object sent not three? It should've been something like `$obj=json_decode($_GET['jsonObj'])` and the rest of the values taken from the JSON object. Another thing... you're not sanitizing your inputs and feeding that straight into your MySQL database.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. thanks for the tips. I am still a bit new so just getting things to work at this point.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11606240/1031312

Comment: okay i removed the $obj, no problems but not solution..

Comment: Why are you doing a JSON decode on the `$_GET`'s?  Just because you're getting JSON data in return doesn't mean the query string parameters are sent as JSON.

Comment: @user1555800 This is really just a confusion in what getJSON is. getJSON in jquery means `do a GET request that I expect the result from the server to be JSON formated". The responding server should handle the data as a standard GET request (ie. /something?param1=yes&param2=25) and is expected to send back json (so your last json_encode is correct but the data sent to the server is standard GET data, not json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use this:

```
$userName = $obj = json_decode($_GET['userName']);
```

It works correctly

```
$userName = $_GET['userName'];
```

Comment: okay i correct my self, that was the solution. What is json_decode for ?

Comment: @user1555800 take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php Also, obligatory mention that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection as it stands currently...

Comment: if the variable $lowestScoreId contains the following string "' OR '1' =  '1". The condition followed by 'OR' is always true and hence the update might be performed on all the rows of the table. 


`mysql_query("UPDATE highScores
SET name    = '$userName',
    score   = '$userPoints',
    date    = '$currentTime'
WHERE id='' OR '1' =  '1'");`